# vectorize a function on 2 python objects

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to vectorize a function that takes 2 objects as argument such that it takes 2 ndarrays (of length m and n) and returns a matrix of shape (m x n).
Kinda like a tensor product.

I've tried to use numpy.vectorize without much success:

```
vFunc = np.vectorize(myFunc)
arg1 = np.asmatrix(a)
arg2 = np.transpose(np.asmatrix(b))
test = vFunc(arg1,arg2)
```

The above doesn't work, so for now I have to iterate on one of the arrays, which is an ugly solution. How do I fix this?

```
vFunc = np.vectorize(myFunc)
arg1 = np.asmatrix(a)
arg2 = np.transpose(np.asmatrix(b))
for i in range(arg1.size): cMat[i,] = vFunc(arg1[i],arg2)
```

Comment: Post your `myFunc`, `a`, `b` as an example will help a lot.

Comment: Do you actually need `a` as a numpy *matrix* as opposed to a numpy array? Numpy matrices are rare in practice.

Comment: Also, is performance an issue? Because using `np.vectorize` is essentially a loop

Comment: does `myfunc` take 2 scalars?  `np.vectorize(myfunc)(a, b[:,None])` should evaluate it with every pair of values from `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic `vectorize` setup:

```
In [420]: def myfunc(x,y):
     ...:     return 10*x + y
     ...: 
In [421]: f = np.vectorize(myfunc)
In [422]: f(np.arange(4), np.arange(3)[:,None])
Out[422]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32]])
```

How is your case different?  Don't just say 'it doesn't work'!

With this particular function, I don't even need `vectorize`:

```
In [423]: myfunc(np.arange(4), np.arange(3)[:,None])
Out[423]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 20, 30],
       [ 1, 11, 21, 31],
       [ 2, 12, 22, 32]])
```

The actions within `myfunc` already work fine with `broadcasting`

`myfunc(np.asmatrix(np.arange(4)), np.asmatrix(np.arange(3)).T)` also works, but the conversion to matrix isn't needed, and is generally discouraged.